# AWS service for running a job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have a NodeJS job that runs every 5min, query DB (MySql and PostgreSQL) and based on result - prepare and send email to recipients.

Currently job is running good on one EC2 every 5min. Now I want to make solution more robust and prepare for any outage (e.g. having another EC2 ready with the same code and logic in another Region that will take over if first EC2 goes down).

What AWS service is best suited for this? Currently thinking between Auto Scaling Group (which could detect and spin another EC2 with the same code if first EC2 is down), Elastic Beanstalk and maybe even Lambda (that will trigger every 5min)..

What is advisable service for this assuming that is OK to have service down 5-10min max during outage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) which is a functions as a service. Since you have a nodejs code written, You will be able to simply convert it to an AWS Lambda function.

Lambda offers, high availability, high scalablility. You can schedule a cloudwatch event to trigger this lambda each 5 mins which is your requirement.

At the moment lambda can handle tasks which are running for 300 seconds. So if your function can execute within the time frame, this would be a great solution.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation! Just in case it does not fit Lambda (e.g. if needs to run more than 300sec or any other reasons) - what would be recommended second solution? Thanks.

Comment: If it needs more than 300 seconds, other than using EC2 instance with ASG, you could containerize your application and use Amazon ECS service. However still ECS uses EC2 underneath, but allows you to use the resources to a maximum level and take off heavy lifting to a certain level. If you are familiar with Docker, ECS may be the next best option. Hope this helps